# Belly Lump with Black Liquid Inside on 9-week-old Pup

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, skin-condition, emergency

First post - sorry for bad quality. I need help fast while my girlfriend takes my pup to the emergency vet.

My 9-week-old female Goldendoodle pup developed a lump this morning and it became significantly larger tonight with black stuff inside. I'm worried.

[image]
Any idea what this is? If it's a super common benign phenomenon then I'd rather not have to waste my money but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Pets SE, could you please include some photos of this lump, thanks.

Comment: @lila Just got the picture. Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a blood blister, which can form on a healing inscision (e.g. after spaying / neutering) when the surture material doesn't dissolve completely. It doesn't look like your dog has had any inscision, so I'm not sure where this could come from.

Answer (score 3):

The emergency vet said it's a blood blister likely from fast crawling under tight spaces (bed, couch) with her belly.